# Hosting Office Templates in a Document Library (Office & SharePoint 2010)

Tags: document-library, office-integration, document-template

I know, SharePoint added this wonderful feature with those document templates, where i can stick a document directly onto a library, and integrate it into SharePoint with some simple clicks (and an Office restart).

My company has several different documents all over the place, hanging in the department's document libraries, and the management asked me now to search for an easy method to integrate all those document templates into the users office applications (in Create what and Save where menu).

I found out that there is the possibility to setup "Published links to Office client applications" in Central Admin -> User Profile Service, and i tried to add link of the type "Document Library with Template Synchronization", but had no luck with that yet.

[image]

Sadly, i found nothin helpfull on google at all whith the query "Document Library with Template Synchronization" beside [Microsoft's patent](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2009/0172005.html) for this feature and the [specification of the link to office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd928756%28v=office.12%29.aspx)...

I tried searching for the german translation and [found a blog from austria](http://translate.google.de/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://www.SharePointblog.at/post/2011/06/10/Dokumenten-Management-Vorlagen-Office-und-die-zentrale-Verwaltung.aspx#comment&act=url), talkin about that feature and how to enable it.

So i created a new Documentlibrary called "DocumentTemplates", gave everyone the rights to read & write, and added the Link of type "Document Library with Template Synchronization" directly to the librarys path (SharePoint/DocumentTemplates/).

After a restart of the Office application i still dont see a new entry in Word -> New -> SharePoint Templates.

So, my question ... How do i setup my SharePoint & my Office to fetch all the Document Templates from this Document Library, and the second - how do i deploy this setting to EVERYONE in my company? The template should NOT force to create a document in SharePoint, and i dont want to create a contenttype for every documenttemplate either.

Comment: From your description I understood that you configured links on sharepoint server but not rolled up them to clients?

Comment: I added the links - the question was how to roll them out to the clients then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see the libraries listed in word when you go file > new? If not you haven't connected the library to office which is required for you to see the templates.

Here is a much better guide than the one you followed, it seems to have some parts missing probably because of the translation.

Check the section called **"To Publish Links to Office Client Applications follow these steps:"**

[**Access SharePoint templates from Office client application**](http://havivi.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/access-sharepoint-templates-from-office.html)

I used this guide the first time I did it and it worked, it also provides debugging solutions at the bottom of the blog.

Comment: He is using the type "Document Library" which is allowing me to display all the Word Templates which are templates in a contenttype of the documentlibrary. I am atempting to use the type "Document Library with Template Synchronization", which should allow me to display Word Templates which are IN that document library.

Comment: And it's not working? Do the templates show up if you try and link to the library manually?

Comment: Well template sync is only avaiable as linktype in central admin... I dont See the link coming up in office at all..

Comment: Well ran through everythin and had to figure out that creating a templatelibrary and readonl librarys where i am adding the contenttypes into with documenttemplates out of that templatelibrary is the best way to go. In addition to that i was able to link the users public sharefolder into webdav of the templatelibrary to offer those templates to all clients live & without having to wait for this buggy feature to update..

Answer (score 0):

I think that this option publish templates for My Sites only, thats why is stored under User Profile Service page in CA. And you have [two ways](http://havivi.blogspot.cz/2012/01/access-sharepoint-templates-from-office.html) how to see them in Word.

You can connect documents like templates from any library by click on "[Add to SharePoint Sites](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/07/consumin-sharepoint-content-types-in-office-2010/)" link from ribbon menu, but it could not be easily spread to all computers in company, it's task for AD admins and group policy I think.

If you want to manage content types automatically for whole portal, use [content type hub](http://www.sharepointworld.in/2012/03/configuring-content-type-hub.html) instead. You can manage and publish all your content types from one library.

Comment: I need a solution which i can easily roll out to all departments / Office-Clients, And i want to manage Office Document Templates in a Library, not Contenttypes in a Hub..

Comment: It is not possible to add SharePoint templates for all users into office, they should do it manually (just once, when new computer / laptop will be prepared, helpdesk/service desk can do it). Our AD admins try to work with it year or so in the past but GPO was so difficult to manage, all users must have a profile (My Site) on SP first, so hard for new computer prepared on helpdesk... See this link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winserverGP/thread/a959f229-d39e-43f0-8c4e-42236d84ab22

Answer (score 0):

Since some years, you can achieve this with use of an Asset Library, called: SharePoint Organization Asset Library. Recently I have applied this via SharePoint Online Management Shell as a SharePoint Admin. At the following links you can find more on how this can be realized:

[Create an organization assets library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/organization-assets-library)

[Add-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/add-spoorgassetslibrary?view=sharepoint-ps)